# List or dictionary?

Tags: python, containers

I have some set of values to be stored in some container to be later retrieved solely by position, like this for an example:

```
index:0
value:(30,6700,3,21543)
index:34
value:(2,1)
index:36
value:(1,2,3,4,5,6,1001,9999)
index:69
value:(11)
```

The other places are empty. Approximately only 1/4 of them have values.

Later I will need to access and modify (append) these values by doing something like `myList[34]=(2,1,9999,999999,9999999)`.

Then I will need to do this: is `9999 in myList[34]`? is `120 in myList[34]`?

I don't know if I should create a dictionary to store them as key-value pairs, or use a list. List seems like the most intuitive way, but then most of the slots in the list would be really empty.

Which is faster, a list or a dict? Or is there any other data containers with better time performance?

Time is my top concern. I wrote a small piece of code yesterday and it has been running 20+ hours. Am very frustrated :-(

Comment: If your indexes are going to be whole numbers (not floats), then a dict is the best choice, especially if you want to add/remove things later. Making a 100-item list just to have actual values in a few spots is not the way to go.

Comment: Seems like what you want is a dict of sets instead of a list of tuples. Set membership testing is O(1) average case. Dict lookup is also O(1) average case.

Comment: a dictionary is better here. they only seem less intuitive to you because you used them not as often as lists. in fact, storing key:value pairs is exactly what you are trying to do and therefore a dictionary should be the intuitive solution.

Comment: "Time is my top concern". If that's true, the wasted space of a list may not matter.

Comment: Your code is likely slow not due to your choice of data structure, but because you're doing something like looping over hundreds of thousands of entries, and looping is slow in Python. Use a dict because it's more natural than a list here, but consider profiling your code to see what the real issue is.

Answer (score 2):

## Speed: list*

## Best coding practices: dictionary

*** Iff** you have enough memory to store the list and the data set does not grow/shrink a lot, then using a list will be fastest.

If either the data set grows/shrinks a lot, or you can't fit it all in memory, then you have to use a dictionary.

---

Note that my above recommendation of the list is for speed only - it's not good coding practices.

Comment: Say if I do have enough space to store a list. I actually know how much the data grows. Each entry grows 15 times, by a length of no more than 15. They never shrink. The question is, would the large size of this list make any difference in time? My code is for actual use, not just practices.

Comment: @MarvellousMartha [Best coding practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_coding_practices) has nothing to do with practice :). And when I said the list should not grow/shrink much, I meant the number of elements in the list, not the size of the individual elements.

Comment: Oh. The thing is for my use only. If something can reduce the time I wait at my computer from 10 days to 9 days, I would gladly toss away any coding practices. I could make the list to have enough empty slots ready when I initiated it, but what about the size of individual elements? Could I do that as well? Will frequent change in size make the list slow?

Comment: @MarvellousMartha You can't do it for individual elements. Also, look into PyPy if speed matters.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing elements by index in both lists and dicts is O(1) - see the [Python wiki entry on time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for more details.

Given that, the most significant issue here is space, and since you say your collection is sparse a dict would be the preferred choice.

Comment: The fact that both are O(1) doesn't tell you much - list indexing could be 5 times faster.

Comment: According to some `timeit` tests I just did, a dictionary with integer keys is virtually the same speed as a list. Integers are their own hash, so there's no hash calculation.

Comment: I'll take that back... it seems to depend somewhat on what key you're accessing. Still, even in the worst case, the dict was still about two thirds the speed of the list's best case. I compared `timeit("a[50000]", "a={x:x for x in range(100000)}")` to `timeit("a[50000]", "a=list(range(100000))")` I would assume that in most real-world applications, that would be swamped by whatever else you're doing.

Comment: Somehow that sounds backwards to me. If that is true, does it mean the largeness of a list actually do make it slower?

Answer (score 0):

For the case you're describing, you definitely want a `dict` over a `list`; that way you only use space for the items that are present.

For the *contents* of your dict you want to have `set(..)` instead of tuples; that will make your `in` checks constant-time instead of length-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a dictionary, since you know the index where you want to put your items (the key). Making a list/array where only a quarter of the positions have values, is not the way to go here. It will make things unnecessarily difficult. Plus the list/array would be far greater than the space that you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a dictionary.

Both a dictionary and a list have O(1) average case lookup times.

It will save on space to use a dictionary though opposed to wasting space on unused list indexes.